# Анимированный слайд-переход между activity

Tags: android, анимация, activity

Хочу добавить анимированный переход между несколькими активити. Требуется при нажатии кнопки осуществить смену одного экрана (активити) другим по типу слайда, как тут: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_screenslide.mp4:

```html
<video src="http://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_screenslide.mp4" autoplay controls loop/>
```

В поисках решения натыкался либо на громоздкие варианты, либо на варианты с использованием фрагментов, использование ViewPager и ViewFlipper в пределах одного активити. Есть ли какие-то более простые варианты?

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сделать [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) сразу после старта активити.
Например:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation1, R.anim.animation2);
```

animation1 - это анимация для запускающейся активити, animation2 - это анимация для уходящей активити.

P.S.: примеры анимации можете посмотреть на сайте Александра Климова. Там ваша задача более подробно разжевана: [клац!](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/overridependingtransition.php)